# Create json from pandas dataframe with index datetime

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have some trouble to save a pandas dataframe in json:

I know pandas.DataFrame.to_json but still have problem to go

from this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [2, 3]],

                  index=pd.to_datetime(['2020-02-03 02:59:33', '2020-02-06 02:44:33']),

                  columns=['Var1', 'Var2'])
```

to this:

```
Var1=df.columns[0]
Var2=df.columns[1]

dev='mydevice'
json={
        "device":dev,
        "signals":{
                      Var1: 
                      {"history" : [
                        {"value" : 0,"date" : "2020-02-03T02:59:33.000+0000"},
                        {"value" : 2,"date" : "2020-02-06T02:44:33.000+0000"}
                            ]}},
                      Var2: 
                      {"history" : [
                        {"value" : 1,"date" : "2020-02-03T02:59:33.000+0000"},
                        {"value" : 3,"date" : "2020-02-06T02:44:33.000+0000"}
                            ]}}
```

Date is obliged to this second format output

Ty all for yout time, I am here to solve any eventual doubt on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the desired output with `df.to_dict()` and a nested loop.

```py
    signals = {}
    for key, val in df.to_dict(orient='dict').items():
        signals[key] = {'history': []}
        for k, v in val.items():
            signals[key].get('history').append({'value': v, 'date': k.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000+0000')})
    json_ = {"device": 'mydevice',
             "signals": signals}
```

Result:

```
{'device': 'mydevice',
 'signals': {'Var1': {'history': [{'date': '2020-02-03T02:59:33.000+0000',
                                   'value': 0},
                                  {'date': '2020-02-06T02:44:33.000+0000',
                                   'value': 2}]},
             'Var2': {'history': [{'date': '2020-02-03T02:59:33.000+0000',
                                   'value': 1},
                                  {'date': '2020-02-06T02:44:33.000+0000',
                                   'value': 3}]}}}
```

Comment: It works ty very much. there is a particular way in wich that  form of data is called?

Comment: Haven't seen it before. But this doesn't mean much. There are so many JSON schemas out there. :)

Comment: ty i appreciated your help